# No module found _winreg python 2.7 windows 7(64-bit)

Tags: python-2.7

Am learning making back-end apps for android using Google App Engine in python.
In a simple hello world program, when I import "mechanize" lib, it goves error "No Module found _winreg".

Python code:

> import webapp2, sys
>   sys.path.append('D:\Project BCA\Python Work\Learning\learner\libs')
>   import mechanize
>   class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>       def get(self):
>           self.response.write('Hello World')
>   app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>       ('/', MainHandler)
>   ], debug=True)

Error Report:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle

```
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler

```
handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject

```
obj = __import__(path[0])
```

File "D:\Project BCA\Python Work\Learning\learner\main.py", line 19, in

```
import mechanize
```

File "D:\Project BCA\Python Work\Learning\learner\libs\mechanize__init__.py", line 164, in

```
from _msiecookiejar import MSIECookieJar
```

File "D:\Project BCA\Python Work\Learning\learner\libs\mechanize_msiecookiejar.py", line 16, in

```
import _winreg
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 851, in load_module

```
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
```

ImportError: No module named _winreg

INFO     2014-02-28 23:51:39,763 module.py:612] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2014-02-28 23:51:39,838 module.py:612] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-02-28 23:51:39,845 module.py:612] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -

Can anyone please help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: See this answer in another similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/44001899/6688123](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44001899/6688123)