# Unable to import _winreg in Python 2.7.9 virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, python-2.7, winreg

I'm running an app engine application in a virtual environment on windows 7 64bit, python 2.7.9 x64.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
    p_system = platform.system()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\platform.py", line 1310, in system
    return uname()[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\platform.py", line 1206, in uname
    release,version,csd,ptype = win32_ver()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\platform.py", line 597, in win32_ver
    import _winreg
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 945, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
  ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

However, it works just fine from cli (outside venv):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Admin>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _winreg
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>>
```

Why does this happen? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: you mean the application `virtualenv`? you probably need to install winreg? or win32api

Comment: _winreg is a part of python, so it's not on pypi and I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: @JoranBeasley, `_winreg` is normally built into python27.dll (see `sys.builtin_module_names`). This environment obviously excludes it because it's sandboxed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Module `_winreg`, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) say, exists to "expose the Windows registry API to Python".

App Engine does not supply a "Windows registry API" (nor any other Windows-specific API).  Therefore, its **sandbox** blocks attempts to `import` the module -- note, at the end of your stack trace, that the exception is deliberately raised in module `sandbox.py` of the App Engine SDK.

Python's "virtual env" plays no part here -- it's all about App Engine.

Please clarify what task you're trying to accomplish with `_winreg` once your GAE app is deployed -- assume it's deployed to Linux servers (although the GAE runtime doesn't supply Linux-specific APIs either:-), so there is no Windows Registry API anywhere in the neighborhood...

Comment: The OP is trying `platform.system()`, which really should handle this scenario more gracefully.

Comment: It calls `platform.uname()`, and on Windows that calls `platform.win32_ver()`. This leaks the `ImportError` instead of handling it as it does  `AttributeError` for `sys.getwindowsversion`. Without access to the registry, it should fall back on parsing environment variables and the output of the `ver` command. For the latter, in 2.x `platform._syscmd_ver` may still fail ungracefully if a `RuntimeError` is raised by `popen`, such as when `%COMSPEC%` is undefined. `_PyPopenCreateProcess` should raise `OSError` for this; a `RuntimeError` is overkill.

Comment: Please open an issue on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list -- ideally amply explaining the task that requires calling `platform.whatever` in the first place, in the face of App Engine's determined, architected attempts to hide what platform the servers are running on, to focus on 100% platform independence:-).  At least, sharper, earlier, more in-your-face exceptions might be raised to diagnose such attempts to breach the sandbox...

Comment: I've never used GAE. In production does it substitute its own platform module and modify the sys module such as `sys.platform`, etc? Specifically in this case I was thinking this is a Python 2.x issue. `platform.win32_ver` should gracefully handle the absence of `_winreg`. On most systems the only information that `platform.win32_ver` doesn't get from `sys.getwindowsversion` is the kernel type (uniprocessor/multiprocessor and free/checked).

Comment: @eryksun, no, GAE just doesn't supply platform info -- it'a a PaaS (Platform as a Service) and keeps enough degrees of freedom to theoretically "switch platforms from under you" in the middle of things.  If you have a use case that's hurt by this, opening a feature request on the issue tracker (with full explanation of what necessary task this stops you from performing) is the only way to perhaps get this changed one day.

Comment: Hi all, does [this seem relevant?](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests), "To use `requests`, you'll need to install both `requests` and `requests-toolbelt` using the vendoring instructions.

Once installed, use the `requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine` module to configure `requests` to use `URLFetch`:"

Answer (score 4):

The workaround provided by Google, until a fix is implemented, is as follows:

- Go to: `<sdk_root>\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py`
- Find the definition of `_WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES = [xxx]`
- Add the following two lines to the list:

`'_winreg',`

`'_ctypes',`

If this does not succeed, run `python -m pip install google-cloud`

Comment: I now get "NameError: global name '_dlopen' is not defined" error. Do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that GAE is not aware that you are in development mode, I suppose because the SERVER_SOFTWARE variable is set to something not starting with "Dev".

If you execute the following code (before calling any GAE library) it should fix the issue:

```
import os
os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = 'Dev'
```

Note: Make sure this code is removed before going to production.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a few days ago.

As said above, the GAE sandbox on Windows blocks some routines or libraries, even built-in one, because it is developed to Unix-like platform.

I opened an issue to Google Team and they passed a workaround:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38290292

That workaround worked well.