# Upload image to S3 with python webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I want to upload the image to Amazon S3. I am using webapp2 python. After some exploration i find out that boto could be useful to upload the images to S3. I installed the boto but when i import it the following error occurred:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 964, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

Import Code:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
```

Python version: 2.7 | Boto latest version.

I did not found any example which can help me to start. I am going to use the S3 service for the first time. Can any body help me with it or suggest me any other method which i can use

Thank You.

Comment: show your import code.  specify which version of Python you are using.  specify if you are in a virtualenv or not.  specify the version of boto.  give people a chance at answering.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: You mentioned latest boto version. Boto latest version is boto3.  Please let us know the exact version

Comment: I installed boto using "pip install boto" I think it installed the latest one.

Comment: Just for testing purpose. Just remove code related to boto including import boto and try running. I think the error you are getting has nothing to do with boto library.

Comment: Traceback points toward sandbox.py which is related to Google App Engine

Comment: Thank you @DineshPundkar I already tried. Their is no issue with the app engine.

Comment: Ok. Try to run two lines of boto code in your environment and check error is coming or not.

Comment: >>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.connect_s3()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect_s3'

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have a dependency on the [_winreg](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) module, as evinced by the error message

> ImportError: No module named _winreg

Since you're running your code on the AppEngine within Windows, the issue may be happening because your code needs Windows registry access, and it is unable to access the _winreg module because AppEngine's sandbox blocks the access. You can find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640983/unable-to-import-winreg-in-python-2-7-9-virtual-environment).

Try running your code in a local Python environment rather than under AppEngine, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I think you forgot to attach the link

Comment: Link fixed. As a FYI it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640983/unable-to-import-winreg-in-python-2-7-9-virtual-environment